# Centering description vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment, description

I have a description environment and would like to center the descriptions vertically w.r.t respect to the items (which are images).

```
\begin{description}
    \item[\pict1] - Description
\end{description}
```

`\pict1` is rather large compared to the height of the description text. As it is, it is put at the "base line" (the bottom of the image) and I would like it to be centered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure that `description` is the best way do to this; I'd use

```
\begin{flushleft}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{pict1}}
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\usebox0}\quad
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd0-1em}
Description
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
```

The main problem is in fact that the description text height is not known in advance. This could be easily made up into a new environment.

Here's an example:

[image]

If your descriptions are only one line long, then a different and simpler approach can be used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelwidth=3cm]

\item[{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=2.5cm]{a}}] Description a

\item[{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=1.5cm]{b}}] Description b

\item[{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=2cm]{b}}] Description c

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the parameters to `description` to suit you. The key is `valign=c` provided by `adjustbox`.

[image]

Comment: The description environment is optimal in that I sort of want to do what css or wpf does. i.e., Apply a "style" to a bland environment to make it look better but otherwise keep the content the same. I have multiple item/descriptions and I'm using multicols. Everything works very simply except for the centering.

Comment: @Uiy As I said, the main problem is that the description is not known in advance, but only when the next `\item` is found. A solution simply with `\item` requires to know more about your possible text and also about the width of the labels/pictures and relative alignment of the texts.

Comment: Why can't the description itself use the it's item to determine it the center value and then center itself in that? e.g., the description gets the previous item's height and divides by 2. This then is the "center" value that the description will use as it's center value. It seems as if your trying to center the item to the description when I want to center the description to the item.

Comment: @Uiy Because the item text is *not* gathered as an argument. If you're willing to accept a different syntax, then it's feasible.

Comment: I don't mind a different syntax or having to specify the offset height of description. In my case they are all single lined text and the item height's are approximately all the same. Not an ideal solution but simply need something that will work inline with what I have(the multicols stuff).

Comment: @Uiy I've added a different approach, based on your comment.

Comment: That is visually what I want but I'm not using includegraphics ;/ I'm using tikz to generate the pictures ;/ If you wrap the tikzpicture in an \adjustbox{valign=c}{...} it will give the effect. Thanks!